# code for a two player dice game won't loop five times

Tags: python

I'm making a two player dice game and this is some of the code for it. I want it to loop five times but it will not do so. Once it has executed all this code, it stops there and doesn't repeat 5 times. I've tried doing for x in range (0, 5) but that doesn't seem to work either. What is the problem with the code and can anyone help fix this?
Btw please ignore the comments, it is for the purpose for an assignment.

```
for x in range(5): #loops the following code 5 times
import random #imports a random module

print ("Player1, it's your turn to play") #prints message
while True: 
    roll = input("Type roll to roll the dice: ") #asks user for input to assign value to variable
    if roll == "roll" or roll == "Roll" : #takes place if the condition is true
        die = random.randint(1, 6) #assigns a random integer value to the variable
        dieOne = random.randint(1, 6) #assigns a random integer value to the variable
        print ("You rolled : ", die, "and", dieOne) #prints a message telling the player what numbers they rolled on the dice
        scoreOne = scoreOne + die + dieOne #assigns the value
        if die == dieOne : #loops only if the condition here is true
            print ("You rolled a double!") #a message that tells the player they rolled a double
            print ("Roll again!") #prints a message
            die = random.randint(1, 6) #assigns a random integer value to the variable
            print ("You rolled : ", die) #prints a message telling the player what number they rolled
            scoreOne = scoreOne + die #adds the value of two variables together
            
    print ("Player2, it's your turn to play") #prints message
    roll2 = input("Type roll to roll the dice: ") #asks user for input to assign value to variable
    if roll == "roll" or roll == "Roll" : #takes place if the condition is true
        dieTwo = random.randint(1, 6) #assgins a random integer value to this variable
        playerTwoDie = random.randint(1, 6) #assgins a random integer value to this variable
        scoreTwo = scoreTwo + dieTwo + playerTwoDie #assigns the value of the previous variable to this variable
        print ("You rolled : ", dieTwo, "and", playerTwoDie) #prints a message telling the player what numbers they rolled on the dice
        break
    if dieTwo == playerTwoDie : #loops only if the condition here is true
        print ("You rolled a double!") #a message that tells the player they rolled a double
        print ("Roll again!") #outputs a message
        dieTwo = random.randint(1, 6) #assigns a random integer value to the variable
        print ("You rolled : ", dieTwo) #prints a message telling the player what number they rolled
        scoreTwo = scoreTwo + dieTwo #adds the value of two variables together
        break
        if die % 2 == 0 : #loops if the value of the variable has a remainder of 0 when divided by 2
            scoreOne = scoreOne + 10 #adds 10 to the value of this variable
        elif dieOne % 2 == 0 : #loops if the value of the variable has a remainder of 0 when divided by 2
            scoreOne = scoreOne + 10 #adds 10 to the value of this variable
        else : #when the above conditions are not true the following code is executed
            scoreOne = scoreOne - 5 #takes away 5 from the value of this variable
        
if scoreOne < 0 : #checks if this condition is true so it can execute the code
    scoreOne = 0 #assigns the value 0 to the variable
    
if dieTwo % 2 == 0 : #loops if the value of the variable has a remainder of 0 when divided by 2
    scoreTwo = scoreTwo + 10 #adds 10 to the value of this variable
elif playerTwoDie % 2 == 0 : #loops if the value of the variable has a remainder of 0 when divided by 2
    scoreTwo = scoreTwo + 10 #adds 10 to the value of this variable
else : #when the above conditions are not true the following code is executed
    scoreTwo = scoreTwo - 5 #takes away 5 from the value of this variable

if scoreTwo < 0 : #checks if this condition is true so it can execute the code
    scoreTwo = 0 #assigns the value 0 to the variable

print ("Player 1, your score so far is: ", scoreOne) #prints a message teller player 1 their score
print ("Pleyer 2, your score so far is: ", scoreTwo) #prints a message telling player 2 their score

break #ends the while loop

print ("Player 1, your total score is: ", scoreOne) #prints message with player one's scores
print ("Player 2, your total score is: ", scoreTwo) #prints message with player two's scores

while scoreOne == scoreTwo : #loop continues when the condition here is true
    print("You have the same score as each other. Lets play again until one person wins!") #prints a message
    import random #inports a random module

print("Player 1, it's your turn to play!")
roll = input("Type roll to roll the dice: ") #asks user for input to assign value to variable
while roll != "roll" or roll != "Roll" : #loops while the condition is true
    print ("Error, please try again!") #prints message
    roll = input("Type roll to roll the dice: ") #asks user for input to assign value to variable
    if roll == "roll" or roll == "Roll" : #takes place if the condition is true
        die = random.randint(1,6) #generates a random integer value for variable
        print ("Your rolled: ", die) #prints message telling the player the value of the variable
        scoreOne = scoreOne + die
        break #ends loop

    print("Player 2, it's your turn to play!")
    roll = input("Type roll to roll the dice: ") #asks user for input to assign value to variable
    while roll != "roll" or roll != "Roll" : #loops while the condition is true
        print ("Error, please try again!") #prints message
        roll = input("Type roll to roll the dice: ") #asks user for input to assign value to variable
        if roll == "roll" or roll == "Roll" : #takes place if the condition is true
            dieTwo = random.randint(1, 6) #generates a random integer value for variable
            print ("Your rolled: ", dieTwo) #prints message telling the player the value of the variable
            scoreTwo = scoreTwo + dieTwo
            break #ends loop
                
if die % 2 == 0 : #loops if the value of the variable has a remainder of 0 when divided by 2
    scoreOne = scoreOne + 10 #adds 10 to the value of this variable
elif dieOne % 2 == 0 : #loops if the value of the variable has a remainder of 0 when divided by 2
    scoreOne = scoreOne + 10 #adds 10 to the value of this variable
else : #when the above condition is not true the following code is executed
    scoreOne = scoreOne - 5 #takes away 5 from the value of this variable
if scoreOne < 0 : #checks if this condition is true so it can execute the code
    scoreOne = 0 #assigns the value 0 to the variable
    
if die2 % 2 == 0 : #loops if the value of the variable has a remainder of 0 when divided by 2
    scoreTwo = scoreTwo + 10 #adds 10 to the value of this variable
elif playerTwoDie % 2 == 0 : #loops if the value of the variable has a remainder of 0 when divided by 2
    scoreTwo = scoreTwo + 10 #adds 10 to the value of this variable
else : #when the above condition is not true the following code is executed
    scoreTwo = scoreTwo - 5 #takes away 5 from the value of this variable

if scoreTwo < 0 : #checks if this condition is true so it can execute the code
    scoreTwo = 0 #assigns the value 0 to the variable
    
print ("Player 1, your score so far is: ", scoreOne) #prints a message teller player 1 their score
print ("Player 2, your score so far is: ", scoreTwo) #prints a message telling player 2 their score
```

Comment: I'm curious what assignment requires you to comment almost every line of code

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `while True`, you can use the following:

```
gamecount = 0
while (gamecount < 5):
   print (f'play game {gamecount}') 
   #insert your other game code here
   gamecount += 1
```

Also remember to remove the `break` in your code as per what @Eliad Cohen said in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

From a first look, this code block won't run unless you move the import to be the first line and indent everything below the "for" loop.What your code is doing now is just importing the random module for five times.
Also, scoreOne needs to be instantiated before it is used in line 11.
I agree with @ycx comment, I think using the while loop will work better. 
I think that your use of `break` in line 57 makes the loop end before you want it to. You can read more about loop control in: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm

Hope this helps so far.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in other answers, the indentation and ordering of your code is off. This may be a programming error or a result of copying the code to stack overflow.

Indentation aside, the script has a lot of repeated code. To reduce duplication of code and make the script easier to read and understand, you may want to split the program into different [functions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp).

Though I do not intend to nulify your previous work, here's my implementation of the game(as I've understood it), so you can get an idea of how one might go about strucuring a simple script. I do realize that there are more elegant ways to implement the game, but for the sake of clarity, I decided to stick to common code constructs.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# imports
from random import randint


# functions
def roll_dice(n_dice):
    """Rolls specified number of dice and returns their values"""
    # wait until the player types 'roll'
    while True:
        answer = input("Type 'roll' to roll the dice: ")
        if answer.lower() == "roll":
            break
    # generate results using list comprehension
    results = [randint(1, 6) for die in range(n_dice)]
    print("you rolled: ", results)
    return results


def play_turn(player_name):
    """Lets specified player play a turn and returns the resulting score"""
    print(player_name, " it's your turn to play!")
    # roll two dice
    roll_one, roll_two = roll_dice(2)
    print(type(roll_one))
    score = roll_one + roll_two

    # if it was a double, roll die no 1 again
    if roll_one == roll_two:
        print("You rolled a double!", "Roll again", sep="\n")
        roll_one = roll_dice(1)[0]
        score += roll_one

    if roll_one % 2 == 0 or roll_two % 2 == 0:  # if at least one die has an even value:
        score += 10
    else:
        score -= 5
    print("you scored", score, "points", "\n")
    return score


def play_game(player_names):
    """runs the game, given a collection of player names"""
    # set up a score board.
    # # This can be implemented more elegantly, but this solution is most clear, I think.
    # the alternative would be a dictionary comprehension: score_board = {player: 0 for player in player_names}
    score_board = dict()
    for player in player_names:
        score_board[player] = 0

    # do 5 rounds of regular playing, adding extra rounds if the game ties
    round_no = 0
    while True:
        for player in player_names:
            score = play_turn(player)
            score_board[player] = max(0, score_board[player] + score)  # make sure the score doesn't drop below 0
        print("current scores are", score_board)
        round_no += 1
        # after 5 normal rounds have been played:
        if round_no >= 5:
            if len(set(score_board.values())) == 1:  # if the game tied:
                print("game tied. Let's play until someone wins!")
                continue
            else:
                # determine who won
                max_score = max(score_board.values())
                for player in score_board:
                    if score_board[player] == max_score:
                        print(player, "won with a score of", max_score)
                return  # a return will exit the function and thus break the loop


def main():
    """The main function controls the entire program on a high level"""
    player_names = ("player 1", "player 2")
    play_game(player_names)
    return


# These lines make sure the game won't start when this file is imported using 'import'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```